# Error load image to image view

Tags: java, android

I have a problem inserting the image in ImageView.
1. The 3.5mb image I insert into ImageView always crashes on the third and fourth images.
2. When the size is app
3. ‎roximately 1.5mb or smaller works well.
4. In point one always Crash on Samsung S7 and when on run in Oppo no problem.
The program is as below, where is the error? thanks advance.

```
`I have a problem inserting the image in ImageView.
```

1. The 3.5mb image I insert into ImageView always crashes on the third and fourth images.
2. When the size is app
3. ‎roximately 1.5mb or smaller works well.
4. In point one always Crash on Samsung S7 and when on run in Oppo no problem.
The program is as below, where is the error? thanks advance.

```
`    ImageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Please Select Image"), Image_Request_Code1);}
        //}
    });
    ImageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Please Select Image"), Image_Request_Code2);}
    //    }
    });
    ImageView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Please Select Image"), Image_Request_Code3);}
    //    }
    });
    ImageView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Please Select Image"), Image_Request_Code4);}
    //    }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Image_Request_Code1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        FilePathUri1 = data.getData();
        try {
            // Getting selected image into Bitmap.
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri1);
            bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,5,baos);
            byte[] BYTE1;
            BYTE1 = baos.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bitmap11 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BYTE1, 0, BYTE1.length);
            // Setting up bitmap selected image into ImageView.
            ImageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap11);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == Image_Request_Code2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        FilePathUri2 = data.getData();
        try {
            // Getting selected image into Bitmap
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri2);
            bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,5,baos);
            byte[] BYTE2;
            BYTE2 = baos.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bitmap22 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BYTE2, 0, BYTE2.length);
            ImageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap22);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == Image_Request_Code3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        FilePathUri3 = data.getData();
        try {
            // Getting selected image into Bitmap.
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap3 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri3);
            bitmap3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,5,baos);
            byte[] BYTE3;
            BYTE3 = baos.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bitmap33 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BYTE3, 0, BYTE3.length);
            ImageView3.setImageBitmap(bitmap33);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == Image_Request_Code4 && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        FilePathUri4 = data.getData();
        try {
            // Getting selected image into Bitmap.
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap4 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri4);
            bitmap4.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,5,baos);
            byte[] BYTE4;
            BYTE4 = baos.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bitmap44 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BYTE4, 0, BYTE4.length);
            ImageView4.setImageBitmap(bitmap44);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: post error logs?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Picasso or Glide library to show Image to ImageView. This library can automatically convert it to Bitmap.

Picasso [Here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Glide   [Here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: Thank you very much quick response Dheeraj, I often use Glide just this time I forgot.